# load base layer from database

Tags: openlayers-2

I have svg maps of floor plans which I am using OpenLayers to project and display interactive features on.

I would like to load the files from my database, (where they are stored as blobs) instead of specifying a path in my file system. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I deserved the vote down... I had a mistake in my code.. used the exact way I load all images dynamically. Don't forget to set the content type:

```
response.setContentType("image/svg+xml");
```